# How to reload current page?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a page for editing user, it has some children components inside. Each children components can change or doing some effect to its parent component.

So instead of emitting the changes to parent and updating some fields, I did a "reload" of the current page with

```
private route: ActivatedRoute;

reload(){
    this.router.navigate(["/admin/user/edit/"+this.user.id]);
}
```

Basically, it redirects to the current page. For example, the current page is 
http://web.info/admin/user/edit/9 it will be redirected to this page with the hope all the data inside that page reloaded with the newest data.

but it seems the angular won't redirect/reload the same page with the `router.navigate`

How I should reload a current page?

Edit:

Here is the reason why I need to reload the page instead of manually updating the data on the current page. I need to do updates on Other Component, when I did the update it will add something to History Component. I need to refresh the User Component and History Component together since both components affected by the changes in Other Component.

[image: Components]

Comment: Look here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13340 You could use simply `window.location.href = '...';`

Comment: i tried using window.location.href = this.router.url .. it works but it doesn't look natural / similiar with other page. I will use this as last resort

Comment: I found a better way than reload the page. instead i will reload the data that just got updated. this way faster n better

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It will work 100%. The following lines of code are responsible for page reload in my project.

```
load(val) {
if (val == this.router.url) {
  this.spinnerService.show();
  this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function () {
    return false;
  };
 }
}
```

Just use the following part in your code.

```
this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function () {
    return false;
  };
```

Comment: am using Angular 9 and this does nothing for me. window.location.reload() works but its a clunk.

Comment: Complete solution needs additional step:`this.router.onSameUrlNavigation = 'reload';` But if you need to reload the page only in specific scenarios, you need to save router state, change to this, make reload and restore state to default.

Comment: This worked perfectly fine for my usecase. Used the 2 liner at the end after using `this.router.navigateByUrl("someUrl")`.

Answer (score 77):

A little bit tricky to do something so simple but had no luck trying to reload and recreate the entire parent & child components with current solution.

Angular Router now provides strategy configuration to tell the Router what to do in case you navigate to the same URL as this user suggests in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13831#issuecomment-422683314).

First of all you can configure what to do while setting up the Router (your router module).

```
@NgModule({
   imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload' })],
   exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Or, if you are like me and don't want to change the entire router module behaviour you can do it with a method/function like this:

```
reloadComponent() {
    this._router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
    this._router.onSameUrlNavigation = 'reload';
    this._router.navigate(['/same-route']);
}
```

Of course you have to first inject `Router` in your component's constructor:

```
// import { Router } from '@angular/router';
...
constructor(private _router: Router){}
...
```

Somehow and as pointed out by @Abhiz **you have to set shouldReuseRoute**, with just configuring the Router by itself the page reload doesn't work with **this aproach**.

I've used an *arrow function* for `shouldReuseRoute`because new TSLint rules won't allow non-arrow functions.

Comment: Thanks, the second approach (not changing entire router behavior) works great on Angular 8.

Comment: would it affect on another routing? or will be destroyed within these changed properties and will not affect to another routers in the project?

Comment: The second method actually affects other routers if you use injection. In my scenario, one of the components uses linear stepper. By changing the strategy, that component went to infinite reload. I finally go with "this.router.navigateByUrl('/', {skipLocationChange: true}).then(() => this.router.navigate(['YourCurrentRoute', this.id]));

Comment: Second Approach works perfectly for Angular 7 also
we can have like this to preseve queryparams also
 
this.router.navigate(['./'], { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute, queryParamsHandling: 'preserve' });

Comment: I made it work without this._router.onSameUrlNavigation = 'reload';

Answer (score 34):

This is the most simple solution if you just need to refresh the entire page

```
   refreshPage() {
    window.location.reload();
   }
```

Comment: this loads all of chunks again man.. not a angular solution

Answer (score 23):

Without specifying the path you can do:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { }

reload() {
  this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
  this.router.onSameUrlNavigation = 'reload';
  this.router.navigate(['./'], { relativeTo: this.route });
}
```

And if you use query params you can do:

```
reload() {
  ...
  this.router.navigate(['./'], { relativeTo: this.route, queryParamsHandling: 'preserve' });
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-refresh-banner-notification',
  templateUrl: './refresh-banner-notification.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./refresh-banner-notification.component.scss']
})

export class RefreshBannerNotificationComponent {

  constructor(
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: Document
  ) {}

  refreshPage() {
    this._document.defaultView.location.reload();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I have solved by this way

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router
          , private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute) {

}
reloadCurrentPage(){
   let currentUrl = this.router.url;
   this.router.navigateByUrl('/', {skipLocationChange: true}).then(() => {
   this.router.navigate([currentUrl]);
   });
 }
```

Comment: best solution, it's not touching angular mechanism and change it. solve it with a simple workaround

Answer (score 4):

Writing this as 2021 (Angular 12 running). **Read explanation or jump to end for straight answer.**

All the answers on this thread and others didn't help me quite much because of unwanted behaviour. What I did instead is implemented a hack.

*Some light on existing answers*

Angular will reload page which means Page Component/Resolvers/Guards in specific way.

using
`this.router.onSameUrlNavigation = 'reload';`

doesn't work most of the time because main purpose of it is to Re-enable Resolvers/Guards. Its mistaken for other meaning though.Also I didn't want to change this across as a global setting so nope!

Another way of `window.location.reload()` OR `window.location.href=window.location.href`
is **worst possible way** as it violates SPA rules. Downloading all chunks again is very bad solution.

While below solution works, for my usecase it was routing twice, so dropped this as well

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('', { skipLocationChange: true }).then(() => {
   this.router.navigate(['/launchpad']);
});
```

Now the **HACK** / **Solution**

Why not tell angular its different route altogether, so reloading is taken care by Angular itself, it also covers guards, resolvers everything. For my usecase

In `app-routing.module.ts` I added **same module with two different routes**

one with '' empty route and one with say 'post-login'

```
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./post-login/post-login.module').then((m) => m.PostLoginModule),
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  },
  {
    path: 'post-login',
    loadChildren: () => import('./post-login/post-login.module').then((m) => m.PostLoginModule),
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  }
```

Now inside wherever I want to reload the same page, Inject router: Router

and use simply like this

```
 this.router.navigateByUrl(this.router.url.includes('post-login') ? '' : 'post-login');
```

*This reloads page with alternate additional 'post-login' in Url but its fine for my usecase. Hope it helps :)*

Comment: This means I can only reload one specific route, i.e. not applicable in all situations.

Answer (score 3):

Because it's the same component. You can either listen to route change by injecting the `ActivatedRoute` and reacting to changes of params and query params, or you can change the default [`RouteReuseStrategy`](https://angular.io/api/router/RouteReuseStrategy), so that a component will be destroyed and re-rendered when the URL changes instead of re-used.

Answer (score 2):

With angular 11 you can just use this:

in route config add `runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'`

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: Component, runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always' },
];
```

and this is your method to reload:

```js
  reloadView(): void {
    this.router.navigated = false;
    this.router.navigate(['./'], { relativeTo: this.route });
  }
```

this will trigger any resolver on that config

Comment: `this.router.navigated = false;` was what I was missing to get `runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'` working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

By this way we can preserve queryparams also

```
 onReloadPage() {
     this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
     this.router.onSameUrlNavigation = 'reload';
     this.router.navigate(['./'], { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute, queryParamsHandling: 'preserve' });
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting `shouldReuseRoute` and `onSameUrlNavigation` properly on the router will force angular to reload when navigating on the same page, however as the `router` is a singleton, it might be relevant to set back its initial values after reloading the page.

This method below will backup and restore the router's settings to prevent side effects to occur. Please comment if you do have a cleaner solution to achieve the same.

```
class MyComponent {

constructor(private router: Router){}

public async reload(): Promise<boolean> {
    const router = this.router;
    const routeReuseStrategy = router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute;
    const onSameUrlNavigation = router.onSameUrlNavigation;
    try {
      router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
      router.onSameUrlNavigation = 'reload';
      return await router.navigateByUrl(router.url);
    } finally {
      router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = routeReuseStrategy;
      router.onSameUrlNavigation = onSameUrlNavigation;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For child and main component, I have written the following code to reload the page

```
reloadCurrentRoute() {
    let currentUrl = this.router.url;
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/', {skipLocationChange: true}).then(() => {
        this.router.navigate([currentUrl]);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Here is the simple one

```
if (this.router && this.router.url === '/') { or your current page url e.g '/home' 
    window.location.reload();
  } else {
    this.router.navigate([url]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe Angular 6 has the BehaviorSubject object.  My sample below is done using Angular 8 and will hopefully work for Angular 6 as well.

This method is a more "reactive" approach to the problem, and assumes you are using and are well versed in rxjs.

Assuming you are using an Observable in your parent component, the component that is used in your routing definition, then you should be able to just pulse the data stream pretty easily.

My example also assumes you are using a view model in your component like so...

```
vm$: Observable<IViewModel>;
```

And in the HTML like so...

```
<div *ngIf="(vm$ | async) as vm">
```

In your component file, add a BehaviorSubject instance...

```
private refreshBs: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
```

Then also add an action that can be invoked by a UI element...

```
  refresh() {
    this.refreshBs.next(1);
  }
```

Here's the UI snippet, a Material Bootstrap button...

```
<button mdbBtn color="primary" class="ml-1 waves-dark" type="button" outline="true"
                    (click)="refresh()" mdbWavesEffect>Refresh</button>
```

Then, in your ngOnIt function do something like this, keep in mind that my example is simplified a bit so that I don't have to provide a lot of code...

```
  ngOnInit() {

    this.vm$ = this.refreshBs.asObservable().pipe(
      switchMap(v => this.route.queryParamMap),
      map(qpm => qpm.get("value")),
      tap(v => console.log(`query param value: "${v}"`)),

      // simulate data load
      switchMap(v => of(v).pipe(
        delay(500),
        map(v => ({ items: [] }))
      )),
      
      catchError(e => of({ items: [], error: e }))
    );
    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

See this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-router-base-2hgd2t?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) which use a `RouteReuseStrategy` in combination with the `onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'` Router option.

This strategy ensures that angular will always re-render the components when navigating to what it considers the "same" route (which includes having different path and query parameters).

```
@Injectable()
export class MyStrategy extends RouteReuseStrategy {
   shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return false;
  }
  store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, detachedTree: DetachedRouteHandle): void {}
  shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return false;
  }
  retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle|null {
    return null;
  }
  shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return false;
  }
}

const routes = [
  {path: '2', component: Empty2},
  {path: '', component: Empty},
];

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'}) ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ], 
  providers: [{provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: MyStrategy}]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score -6):

```
private router: Router

this.router.navigateByUrl(url)
```

It will redirect to any pages without data lost (even current page). Data will remain as is.